# How to use phpamqplib with IBM mq amqp

Tags: ibm-mq, amqp, signals-slots

I am trying to use phpamqplib or pecl amqp to send messages to IBM MQ trough amqp protocol.

With phpamqplib I get:

3/21/20 19:04:28.965 AMQXR0021W: Client 'null' at network address '......' disconnected abnormally 
with exception 'Received fatal alert: unknown_ca'.

I am specifying the cacert and have imported it in the keystore.

Pecl amqp - cannot find working example with ssl .

Is there some php library that I can use for IBM MQ?

Thank you

Comment: Why did you add mqtt if you asked about amqp?

Comment: Some lightweight protocol,  doesn't matter :) both are supported on mq side. Just found this.. but didnt tested yet. https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-library-encyclopedia-mosquitto-php/

Comment: Not as far as I know MQTT on MQ side is not included in the base MQ but AMQP is included in the base MQ.  I think MQTT is part of MQ Advanced only.  I don't know a lot about either so someone with more knowledge will correct me if I am wrong, @roger for example.

Comment: Also you should modify your question to include mqtt if that is what you are know also asking for.

Answer (score 1):

IBM has a support document on using PHP with IBM MQ [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/using-php-access-mq).

In the document, they use [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/mqseries).

There are other PHP/IBM MQ user projects in GitHub:

- [amabnl / php-mqseries](https://github.com/amabnl/php-mqseries)
- [rstmpw / ibmmq](https://github.com/rstmpw/ibmmq)

Comment: Hello Roger, Thanks for the info. Yes but i search how to connect via mqtt or amqp protocol . This mqseries is using another type of connection..

Comment: @Vasilev you asked "Is there some php library that I can use for IBM MQ?".  So, I gave you several solutions.  Also, it is better to use IBM MQ's protocol than to use either MQTT or AMPQ but IBM does support both MQTT and AMPQ protocols.

Comment: Question was connected with the whole topic :)  ok why it is better ?

Comment: First, RTM.  Second, IBM MQ only supports a subset of the MQTT and AMQP protocols (i.e. IBM MQ does not support MQTT v5).  Third, doing PHP -> AMQP -> IBM MQ is taking the long road when it is simpler to do PHP -> IBM MQ.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, will try, although i don't want to change so much on the webserver side .. only in the code. Already created java to upload a file to a queue, but wanted to try with these lightweight protocols.